OpenRewrite - Refaster template recipe is not discoverable and not usable
It is understood that OpenRewrite has 3 main methods of creating recipes: Declarative, Refaster, and Imperative. This is about the Refaster method.
I have created the following Refaster template class for a simple code change - Ensuring that divisions occur after multiplications. (Just an example to test out OpenRewrite's features)
package com.self.openrewrite_lib.refaster;

import com.google.errorprone.refaster.annotation.AfterTemplate;
import com.google.errorprone.refaster.annotation.BeforeTemplate;
import org.openrewrite.java.template.RecipeDescriptor;

@RecipeDescriptor(name = "Multiply then divide formatter", description = "Ensures that divisions occur after multiplication for accuracy.")
public class MultiplyThenDivide {
    @BeforeTemplate
    public double divideThenMultiply(double original, double divisor, double multiplier) {
        return original / divisor * multiplier;
    }
    @AfterTemplate
    public double multiplyThenDivide(double original, double divisor, double multiplier) {
        return original * multiplier / divisor;
    }
}

After running mvn compile in the terminal, the Recipe class is generated within the target/generated-sources/annotations/com/self/openrewrite_lib/refaster directory.
package com.self.openrewrite_lib.refaster;

import org.jspecify.annotations.NullMarked;
import org.openrewrite.ExecutionContext;
import org.openrewrite.Preconditions;
import org.openrewrite.Recipe;
import org.openrewrite.TreeVisitor;
import org.openrewrite.java.JavaParser;
import org.openrewrite.java.JavaTemplate;
import org.openrewrite.java.JavaVisitor;
import org.openrewrite.java.search.*;
import org.openrewrite.java.template.Primitive;
import org.openrewrite.java.template.function.*;
import org.openrewrite.java.template.internal.AbstractRefasterJavaVisitor;
import org.openrewrite.java.tree.*;

import javax.annotation.Generated;
import java.util.*;

import static org.openrewrite.java.template.internal.AbstractRefasterJavaVisitor.EmbeddingOption.*;

/**

* OpenRewrite recipe created for Refaster template {@code MultiplyThenDivide}.
  */
  @SuppressWarnings("all")
  @NullMarked
  @Generated("org.openrewrite.java.template.processor.RefasterTemplateProcessor")
  public class MultiplyThenDivideRecipe extends Recipe {

  /**

  * Instantiates a new instance.
    */
    public MultiplyThenDivideRecipe() {}

  @Override
  public String getDisplayName() {
  return "Multiply then divide formatter";
  }

  @Override
  public String getDescription() {
  return "Ensures that divisions occur after multiplication for accuracy.";
  }

  @Override
  public TreeVisitor\<?, ExecutionContext\> getVisitor() {
  return new AbstractRefasterJavaVisitor() {
  final JavaTemplate divideThenMultiply = JavaTemplate
  .builder("#{original:any(double)} / #{divisor:any(double)} * #{multiplier:any(double)}")
  .build();
  final JavaTemplate multiplyThenDivide = JavaTemplate
  .builder("#{original:any(double)} * #{multiplier:any(double)} / #{divisor:any(double)}")
  .build();

           @Override
           public J visitBinary(J.Binary elem, ExecutionContext ctx) {
               JavaTemplate.Matcher matcher;
               if ((matcher = divideThenMultiply.matcher(getCursor())).find()) {
                   return embed(
                           multiplyThenDivide.apply(getCursor(), elem.getCoordinates().replace(), matcher.parameter(0), matcher.parameter(2), matcher.parameter(1)),
                           getCursor(),
                           ctx,
                           SHORTEN_NAMES
                   );
               }
               return super.visitBinary(elem, ctx);
           }
      
       };

  }
  }

The above can be used when writing OpenRewrite test cases, but when trying to run the recipe on my own code through the mvn rewrite:run command, or attempt to discover the recipe through the mvn rewrite:discover command, the newly generated recipe is not found.
Test case usage (which passes):
package com.self.openrewrite_lib;

import com.self.openrewrite_lib.refaster.MultiplyThenDivideRecipe;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.openrewrite.test.RewriteTest;

class OpenRewriteTests implements RewriteTest {

    @Test
    void multiplyThenDivideRecipe() {
        rewriteRun(spec -> spec.recipe(new MultiplyThenDivideRecipe()),
                //language=java
                org.openrewrite.java.Assertions.java(
                        """
                        class TestExample {
                            public double calculate(double a, double b, double c) {
                                return a / b * c;
                            }
                        }
                        """,
                        """
                        class TestExample {
                            public double calculate(double a, double b, double c) {
                                return a * c / b;
                            }
                        }
                        """
                ));
    }

}

Running mvn rewrite:discover:
Failed to execute goal org.openrewrite.maven:rewrite-maven-plugin:5.42.2:discover (default-cli) on project openrewrite-lib: Could not find recipe 'com.self.openrewrite_lib.refaster.MultiplyThenDivideRecipe' among available recipes -> [Help 1]
Running mvn rewrite:run:
Failed to execute goal org.openrewrite.maven:rewrite-maven-plugin:5.42.2:run (default-cli) on project openrewrite-lib: Execution default-cli of goal org.openrewrite.maven:rewrite-maven-plugin:5.42.2:run failed: Recipe(s) not found: com.self.openrewrite_lib.refaster.MultiplyThenDivideRecipe
Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.
Tutorial / Documentation used for reference: https://docs.openrewrite.org/authoring-recipes/refaster-recipes
pom.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.self</groupId>
    <artifactId>openrewrite-lib</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>openrewrite-lib</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <url/>
    <licenses>
        <license/>
    </licenses>
    <developers>
        <developer/>
    </developers>
    <scm>
        <connection/>
        <developerConnection/>
        <tag/>
        <url/>
    </scm>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.openrewrite.recipe</groupId>
                <artifactId>rewrite-recipe-bom</artifactId>
                <version>2.21.1</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openrewrite</groupId>
            <artifactId>rewrite-java</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openrewrite</groupId>
            <artifactId>rewrite-java-17</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openrewrite</groupId>
            <artifactId>rewrite-yaml</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openrewrite</groupId>
            <artifactId>rewrite-templating</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.errorprone</groupId>
            <artifactId>error_prone_core</artifactId>
            <version>2.34.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.auto.service</groupId>
                    <artifactId>auto-service-annotations</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.34</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openrewrite</groupId>
            <artifactId>rewrite-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M9</version>
            </plugin>
            <!-- lombok is optional, but recommended for authoring recipes -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.13.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>17</source>
                    <target>17</target>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>-parameters</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>1.18.34</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.openrewrite</groupId>
                            <artifactId>rewrite-templating</artifactId>
                            <version>1.16.1</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openrewrite.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>rewrite-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>5.42.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <activeRecipes>
                        <recipe>com.self.openrewrite_lib.refaster.MultiplyThenDivideRecipe</recipe>
                    </activeRecipes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>


Did you mark that target/generated-sources/annotations/ folder as a generated source root? It sounds like your IDE isn't picking that up just yet if the file is present but the class can not be found.
For a reference implementation you can also look towards our rewrite-recipe-starter:
https://github.com/moderneinc/rewrite-recipe-starter/blob/main/pom.xml#L150-L154
I hope that helps!

Hello, I am using IntelliJ, and yes the target/generated-sources/annotations directory is marked as a generated source root (blue folder icon with an asterisk). Since my test class is able to use the generated recipe class, would think it already exists. That's why I was confused when the test works, but the actual recipe usage in pom.xml's rewrite-maven-plugin does not work.

Can you see the generated recipe class in your target folder in the correct package? If not I‘d guess you need to tell maven explicitly about your generated sources directory via build-helper-plugin …
